# Openshift Flask-MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, flask, openshift, flask-mysql

I have a openshift app written in python and would like to use Flask-mysql

```
import os
from datetime import datetime
from flask import Flask, request, flash, url_for, redirect, \
     render_template, abort, send_from_directory, json


from flask.ext.mysql import MySQL


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_pyfile('flaskapp.cfg')
mysql = MySQL()

# MySQL configurations
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = ' adminuWfyNxG'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = ' '
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = ''
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = '127.4.253.2:3306'
mysql.init_app(app)

#conn = mysql.connect()
#cursor = conn.cursor()


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/showSignUp')
def showSignUp():
    return render_template('signup.html')

@app.route('/<path:resource>')
def serveStaticResource(resource):
    return send_from_directory('static/', resource)


@app.route('/signUp',methods=['POST','GET'])
def signUp():
    try:
        _name = request.form['inputName']
        _email = request.form['inputEmail']
        _password = request.form['inputPassword']

        # validate the received values
        if _name and _email and _password:

            # All Good, let's call MySQL

            conn = mysql.connect()
            cursor = conn.cursor()

            cursor.callproc('sp_createUser',(_name,_email,_password))
            data = cursor.fetchall()

            if len(data) is 0:
                conn.commit()
                return json.dumps({'message':'User created successfully !'})
            else:
                return json.dumps({'error':str(data[0])})
        else:
            return json.dumps({'html':'<span>Enter the required fields</span>'})

    except Exception as e:
        return json.dumps({'error':str(e)})
    finally:
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

When I try to run it on my app I receive an error.

HTTP/1.1 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable
Date: Wed, 02 Sep 2015 19:09:34 GMT
Content-Length: 428
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

I use the database user, password, databasename and host as per the openshift config.

Can anyone assist me?

Log file output:

Starting WSGIServer type flask on 127.4.253.1:8080 ...
 * Running on http://127.4.253.1:8080/
127.4.253.1 - - [03/Sep/2015 13:40:33] "GET /showSignUp HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.p
y", line 159, in run_wsgi
    execute(app)
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.p
y", line 146, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "/var/lib/openshift/55d41b2c0c1e66a0060000b8/app-root/runtime/dependencie
s/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.10.1-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py
", line 1836, in **call**
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/var/lib/openshift/55d41b2c0c1e66a0060000b8/app-root/runtime/dependencie
s/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.10.1-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py
", line 1836, in **call**
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/var/lib/openshift/55d41b2c0c1e66a0060000b8/app-root/runtime/dependencie
s/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.10.1-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py
", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/var/lib/openshift/55d41b2c0c1e66a0060000b8/app-root/runtime/dependencie
s/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.10.1-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py
", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/var/lib/openshift/55d41b2c0c1e66a0060000b8/app-root/runtime/dependencie
s/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.10.1-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py
", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/var/lib/openshift/55d41b2c0c1e66a0060000b8/app-root/runtime/dependencie
s/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.10.1-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py
", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/var/lib/openshift/55d41b2c0c1e66a0060000b8/app-root/runtime/dependencie
s/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.10.1-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py
", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/var/lib/openshift/55d41b2c0c1e66a0060000b8/app-root/runtime/dependencie
s/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.10.1-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py
", line 1473, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.preprocess_request()
  File "/var/lib/openshift/55d41b2c0c1e66a0060000b8/app-root/runtime/dependencie
s/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.10.1-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py
", line 1666, in preprocess_request
    rv = func()
  File "/var/lib/openshift/55d41b2c0c1e66a0060000b8/app-root/runtime/dependencie
s/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Flask_MySQL-1.3-py2.7.egg/flaskext/
mysql.py", line 48, in before_request
    ctx.mysql_db = self.connect()
  File "/var/lib/openshift/55d41b2c0c1e66a0060000b8/app-root/runtime/dependencie
s/python/virtenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Flask_MySQL-1.3-py2.7.egg/flaskext/
mysql.py", line 44, in connect
    return MySQLdb.connect(**self.connect_args)
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/**init**
.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connecti
ons.py", line 187, in **init**
    super(Connection, self).**init**(*args, **kwargs2)
OperationalError: (2005, "Unknown MySQL server host '127.4.253.2:3306' (1)")

Comment: What error are you getting in your log files?  https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-log-files.html

Comment: I am receiving the following error: Unknown MySQL server host

Comment: Are you using the environment variables for your mysql connection?

Comment: The host is wrong, it should jsut be the ip address, don't include the port, and you should not post your passwords....

Comment: Tried that, removed the port. still doesnt work. Can we maybe teamviewer?

Comment: Have you looked at [openshift's HOWTO add DB to your app](https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-adding-a-database.html) As I don't see any of it in the output provided. At least the ENV variables are always in form OPENSHIFT_<database>_PORT etc ...